C++ send() slows down when called infrequently
There is a c++ MSDN tcp server and client from here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/finished-server-and-client-code
They do a ping pong: server sends a small tcp packet (10 Bytes) to client, client waits a given wait time, replies with a tcp packet (10 Bytes) to server. Server immediately replies to client and so on.
Server and client are running on a localhost Windows Server 2019 Intel Xeon 2288G (fast hardware, optimized for high performance, C states off).
When the wait time grows from 0 to seconds, the send time on the server side also grows from 5 microseconds to 13 microseconds.
What should be done to keep the send() time at minimum for any wait time?
Relevant code:
Server:
    do {

        iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);

        QueryPerformanceCounter(&counter);   //measure time
        t0 = counter.QuadPart / (double)freq.QuadPart * 1000000;

        iSendResult = send( ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0 );

        QueryPerformanceCounter(&counter);
        T[i] = counter.QuadPart / (double)freq.QuadPart * 1000000 - t0;
        i++;
    } while (i < N);


Client:
    do{
        iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0 );
        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);

        i++;

                //implementation of the delay; varies by changing Cycles from 0 to 3*10^9
        int j = 0;
        double a = 1.000000001;
        do
        {
            a0 = a0 * a;
            j++;
        } while(j < Cycles);

    } while (i < N);

plot of send() time vs wait time

Small packets are buffered until they make a bigger packet, or until "wait to send" timeout happens.  It's called Nagle's algorithm, and you may need to disable it for your connection to get quicker communication, at the expense of more smaller packets.

Thanks, but it seems to be not the case here: Nagle's algo may introduce a delay of 300 ms (and it's disables on my machine), I observe delays of tens of microsecond as if the socket is put to a "sleep state" due to inactivity. It seems the thread itself is not slowed down for computations (only send()/recv() are slow)
